# UIView and UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I'm having trouble trying to code in my tableView. I'll explain... I'm using storyboard and want to make an RSS Feed into my 2nd tab. I'm running through Ray W's tutorial for RSS Feed found here [RSS Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial)

[image: Storyboard]

I'm almost finished with the ASIHTTPRequest part of the tutorial and am up to the point where I need to write this bit of code

`- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {

```
RSSEntry *entry = [[[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:request.url.absoluteString
                                           articleTitle:request.url.absoluteString
                                             articleUrl:request.url.absoluteString
                                            articleDate:[NSDate date]] autorelease];    
int insertIdx = 0;                    
[_allEntries insertObject:entry atIndex:insertIdx];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertIdx inSection:0]]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

}`

My problem is that an error comes up when I type in self.tableView. The error is: **Property 'tableView' not found on object of type 'SecondViewController'

[image: Error]**

The *SecondViewController.h* file has `@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {` so I think that is why the error comes up. When I chance the @interface part to UITableViewController, the error disappears but when I run the project and click on the RSS Feed tab, it will crash with the following error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'`

Does anyone have a fix for this? Thanks.

Comment: Look at the text of the exception. If you're using a subclass of `UITableViewController`, its `view` property **must** be an instance of `UITableView`. On the other hand, it's possible to make a subclass of `UIViewController` into the delegate/dataSource of a table view that is a subview of its main view; just declare that it conforms to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` and go about implementing the delegate methods in the usual way. You just won't get the `tableView` property automatically, but you can always create your own `UITableView` outlet and wire it up yourself.

Comment: @warrenm: Thank you for your prompt reply. Sorry, but I am an absolute noob. Can you please run me through what I need to do in a simpler way? Thanks again.

Comment: I think I have done it. I did the UITableViewDelegate and DataSource by the @interface bit of the .h file. Then underneath that, I wrote UITableViewController *tableViewController; and then in the .m file I replaced self.tableView to  tableViewController.tableView. Is that correct?

Comment: No. Looking at this again, it seems like you actually want `SecondViewController` to be a subclass of `UITableViewController`, but somehow it got created as a subclass of `UIViewController`. Can you post the exact wording of the exception's description (i.e., the internal inconsistency exception that occurs when `SecondViewController` is a `UITableViewController` but seemingly doesn't have its outlets set correctly)?

Comment: Hey, I have uploaded a screenshot of the output. http://imgur.com/1XF9x Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PLease add tableView as a property in the sendViewController and then set its data source
in view did load as:

add in SecondViewController.h

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

add in SecondViewController.h

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .// your code here...
}
```

and finally connect this tableview in your interface builder with the table view..

Hope this Helps.... :)